# Passar valor da view bag para a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando passar valor de uma view bag para a view create.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.BanhoTosaId = new SelectList(db.BanhoTosas, "BanhoTosaId", "Tipo");


    if (ViewBag.BanhoTosaId.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        BanhoTosa BT = db.BanhoTosas.Find(ViewBag.BanhoTosaId);
        decimal valorSoma = BT.Valor + 10;
        ViewBag.Total = valorSoma;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Total = 0;
    }

    return View();
}
```

No caso BT ira pega o valor na tabela de banho e tosa e somar mais 10, e depois ira retorn o valor da soma no viewbag.Total.

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", value = "@ViewBag.Total" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

value = "@ViewBag.Total" era pra supostamente receber o valor da ViewBag.

Comment: Qual valor que está sendo recebido por `value` atualmente?

Comment: @LINQ então o campo editor for não esta recebendo o valor da viewbag.,esta ficando em branco.

Comment: @caiooliveira o seu "não está recebendo" quer dizer que o valor vem 0 ou o valor vem null?

Comment: ata vem null kkk

Comment: @KelvynRisso Vi que vc já resolveu uma questão um pouco parecida aqui no stack, gostaria que vc desse uma olhada na minha pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Então o mais correto seria você criar um ViewModel para essa view, exemplo:

```
public class CreateBanhoTosaViewModel
{
    public int? Total { get; set; }
}
```

Então utilizar no seu controller mais ou menos assim:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //aqui você seleciona o valor do total
    var viewModel = new CreateBanhoTosaViewModel { Total = 1 };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

A sua view vai ter que fazer referência a esse view model utilizando `@model`, ela vai ficar assim:

```
@model App.Models.CreateBanhoTosaViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma você vai estar utilizando corretamente o framework.

De toda forma se você preferir continuar usando o `@ViewBag`, você teria que escrever o controle na mão, mais ou menos assim:

```
<input name="Total" id="Total" value="@ViewBag.Total" />
```

Eu não recomendo você utilizar essa opção.